# ARCore releasing image causing crash

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, arcore

I'm running the hello_ar_c example. When I try to acquire the current CPU image, if I subsequently release it, the app crashes.

```
void HelloArApplication::OnDrawFrame() {
  // Render the scene.
  glClearColor(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 1.0f);
  glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

  if (ar_session_ == nullptr) return;

  ArSession_setCameraTextureName(ar_session_,
                                 background_renderer_.GetTextureId());

  // Update session to get current frame and render camera background.
  if (ArSession_update(ar_session_, ar_frame_) != AR_SUCCESS) {
    LOGE("HelloArApplication::OnDrawFrame ArSession_update error");
  }

  ArCamera* ar_camera;
  ArFrame_acquireCamera(ar_session_, ar_frame_, &ar_camera);

  ArImage* ar_image;
  ArFrame_acquireCameraImage(ar_session_, ar_frame_, &ar_image);

  ArImage_release(ar_image);
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
2020-03-15 18:27:32.211 818-6317/? I/cie: FaceStoryAlgo::isCurFrameRun isCurFrameRun. Process mode 0.  
2020-03-15 18:27:32.212 818-1473/? I/AlgoEvent: [HWA_CAM3]yuv tracking rect[0 0 0 0] raw tracking rect[0 0 0 0] 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.212 818-6311/? D/Misc____: [0b99617d_64D] onProcessFrame(666), afDistance(0.000000)
2020-03-15 18:27:32.212 656-656/? I/mediacomm@2.1-service: getMdcClient:114: get client<Camera, 117, 818>, channel<4, 1>, perfLev=2, powerStatue=0. 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.212 656-656/? I/mediacomm@2.1-service: getMdcVotePerfLev:179: Connected Mdc client<Camera, 117, 818> channel<4, 1> perfLev<2> 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.213 800-1480/? E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.213 800-1480/? E/Camera3-OutputStream: returnBufferCheckedLocked: Stream 1: Error queueing buffer to native window: Broken pipe (-32) 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.213 800-1480/? E/Camera3-Device: Can't return buffer to its stream: (0xe9921480), error: Broken pipe (-32) 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.215 656-656/? I/mediacomm@2.1-service: doCopybit:495: client<Camera, 0> ret = 818 finish copybit -. 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.215 818-6320/? I/GRALLOC: LockFlexLayout: baseFormat: 11, yStride: 640, ySize: 307200, uOffset: 307200,  uStride: 640 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.215 818-6320/? I/GRALLOC: LockFlexLayout: baseFormat: 11, yStride: 640, ySize: 307200, uOffset: 307200,  uStride: 640 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.215 800-1480/? E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.215 800-1480/? E/Camera3-OutputStream: returnBufferCheckedLocked: Stream 0: Error queueing buffer to native window: Broken pipe (-32) 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.215 800-1480/? E/Camera3-Device: Can't return buffer to its stream: (0xe9923700), error: Broken pipe (-32) 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.228 818-6308/? I/HwaStatInfo: [0b99617d_64I] algotype is 0, videoRatio is 1.000000, ratio is 2.666667, faceNum is 0 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.228 818-6322/? I/afstatAlgo: do_afstat_num:0,flow =0, aftype:0, focus_stage = 0,focus_scene:0 fv[code:0 normalFV:0, peakHoldFV:0],frame_rect[0, 0], focus_rect[0 0 0 0] 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.245 818-6317/? I/EnvImpl: [HWA_CAM3]getArCalorieMode mArCalorieMode 0 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.245 818-6315/? I/YuvCalculate: mono_mode: 0, ae_stable: [1, 0], colorDis: 1, buf_cnt:1 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.245 818-6317/? I/cie: FaceStoryAlgo::isCurFrameRun isCurFrameRun. Process mode 0.  
2020-03-15 18:27:32.245 818-6311/? D/Misc____: [0b99617d_64D] onProcessFrame(666), afDistance(0.000000) 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.245 818-1473/? I/AlgoEvent: [HWA_CAM3]yuv tracking rect[0 0 0 0] raw tracking rect[0 0 0 0] 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.246 656-656/? I/mediacomm@2.1-service: getMdcClient:114: get client<Camera, 117, 818>, channel<4, 1>, perfLev=2, powerStatue=0. 
2020-03-15 18:27:32.246 656-656/? I/mediacomm@2.1-service: getMdcVotePerfLev:179: Connected Mdc client<Camera, 117, 818> channel<4, 1> perfLev<2>
```

When I comment out the line that releases the image, the program runs, the background is rendered properly on the screen, but the stacktrace returns:

```
2020-03-15 18:34:27.753 800-6919/? I/Camera3-Stream: getBuffer: Stream 1, 0xe9921300: Already dequeued max output buffers (7), wait for next returned one.
2020-03-15 18:34:27.754 6723-6818/com.google.ar.core.examples.c.helloar E/native: cpu_image_manager.cc:260 Failed to acquire new image, due to too many images acquired but not released.
2020-03-15 18:34:27.754 6723-6818/com.google.ar.core.examples.c.helloar E/native: status.cc:156 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: 
ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/cpu_image_manager.cc:262
 [type.googleapis.com/util.ErrorSpacePayload='ArStatusErrorSpace::AR_ERROR_RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED']
```

I would expect that AR_ERROR_RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED would come up if none of the images are released. I'm just not sure as to why when I try to release the images, I get an app crash.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out:

```
if (ArFrame_acquireCameraImage(ar_session_, ar_frame_, &ar_image) == AR_SUCCESS) {
      ArImageFormat ar_image_format;
      ArImage_getFormat(ar_session_, ar_image, &ar_image_format);
      ArImage_release(ar_image);
  }
```

The code without an if statement (or try maybe) was trying to release the image more than once; this, crashing the app.